# Simplify async-await with array iteration in Typescript

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

Is there a simpler way to express this syntax in Typescript, without `Promise.all` and `Array.prototype.map`?

```
const items = [...];
await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
    doSomething(item);
    const result = await doSomethingAsync(item);
    doSomethingMore(result, item);
});
```

Comment: No. Why do you think it is not simple enough?

Comment: If you want to do all of the promises concurrently you have to use `Promise.all`

Comment: i thought it was just a lot of ceremony and overhead to remember to use `.map`

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't think typescript has any kind of array comprehensions

Comment: @DanielA.White What would you have used but `map` to create the array of promises?

Comment: @Bergi i just didn't want to think about it - i just wish i could say `await items.forEach(async)`

Comment: @DanielA.White You can always write your own helper function that combines the `map` and `Promise.all` call. No, you won't get around it when you want to do things concurrently. (Oh, and stop using `forEach`. `for … of` is more idiomatic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES5 array methods don't fully support `async` and generator functions, that's one of the reasons why `for` and other loop statements should be preferred to `forEach` in ES6.

In this case `map` is partially misused, because it doesn't manage array values. If promises should be resolved in parallel, it likely should be:

```
items = await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
    doSomething(item);
    const result = await doSomethingAsync(item);
    doSomethingMore(result, item);
    return item;
});
```

Not much simpler but possibly semantically correct. If `do..` functions modify `item` to the point its type changes, `const newItems = await Promise.all(...)` also makes it easier to manage item types.

If they should be resolved in series and no `Promise.all` has to be involved, this can be `for..of`:

```
for (const item of items) {
    doSomething(item);
    const result = await doSomethingAsync(item);
    doSomethingMore(result, item);
});
```